# Rudin functional analysis theorem 1.14 part a

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I'm trying to understand. this theorem

**Theorem 1.14.** In a topological vector space ,

**(a)** every neighborhood of 0 contains a balanced neighborhood of 0.

The proof asserts that as scalar multiplication is continuous for every neighborhood of 0 let's call it U there exist $\delta > 0$ and another neighborhood V such that $\alpha V \subset U$ whenever $\left | \alpha \right | < \delta$.

My question: Why is this affirmation true? It is obvious when working on $R^n$ or even $C$ with a topology defined by a metric, however we do not have a norm, metric or even scalar product in the hypothesis.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a topological vector space?

Comment: I think I do, it is a vector space together with a topology where multiplication by scalars and addition of vectors is a continuous operation in that topology. So this condition will restrict the possible topologies I can define there.

Comment: Then what does continuity of scalar multiplication tell you about the question that you have asked?

Comment: With $R$ as a field I can take the same neighborhood $U$, reflect it (multiply by -1) both will be open so it will be their intersection, lets call it V, then V will be what I'm looking for and $\delta = 1$.

My problem is when I think it on $C$ I can take things like $\delta e^{I\beta t}$ which will be also rotating the set and I may need to do a non finite number of intersections which means I can not guarantee that the result will be open or that it will not have non empty interior.


I think I'm missing something silly here.

Comment: @user1880062 you're just scaling down $V$ so that it's in the neighborhood of the origin given by $U$. Doesn't matter what $V$ is as long as it's in some other neighborhood.

Comment: Try to write down in all the detail the definition of continuity (at zero!) of the scalar multiplication in a topological vector space. It has nothing to do with the exponential expression that you wrote in the earlier comment (or the meaningless notion of a rotation in a TVS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I did realize the answer.

Given a topological vector space X and that $\cdot:F\times X \rightarrow X$ is continuous.

Given a neighborhood U of 0 there is a neighborhood $D \times V \subset F \times X$ such that $\cdot$ carries this neighborhood into U (this is because the continuity of $\cdot$).

Now 0 belongs to $D$ meaning that there is $\delta > 0$ such that $B(0,\delta) \subset D$ and for any $\alpha < \delta$ we have that $\cdot(\alpha, V) \subset U$

Comment: Right, that's all.